# Apache after a2ensite can't start and I get error "Address already in use"

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` server and I am facing a strange problem with the Apache web server.

I add a new domain that it will redirect permanently to another domain. So I create a newdomain.com.conf` file which contains

```
 ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
 ServerName newdomainname.com
 ServerAlias www.newdomainname.com
 Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com
```

and I enable it by `a2ensite newdomain.com.conf`. Then, I execute `service apache2 restart` to complete the process where I don't get any error message.

However Apache can't start and the command `service apache2 status` then prints:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2020-03-01 16:05:04 UTC; 27s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 13416 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23983 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13280 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 01 16:05:03 kotronis apache2[13280]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Mar 01 16:05:03 kotronis apache2[13280]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13280]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13280]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13280]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13280]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13280]:  *
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13416]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis apache2[13416]:  *
Mar 01 16:05:04 kotronis systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

If I reboot the server, Apache starts normally and the `service apache2 status` command prints:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-01 16:07:41 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1261 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 11
   Memory: 198.4M
      CPU: 5.500s
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 1440 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1638 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1639 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1642 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1643 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1645 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 1781 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 7891 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 8586 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 8890 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─26106 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Mar 01 16:07:39 kotronis systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Mar 01 16:07:39 kotronis apache2[1261]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar 01 16:07:41 kotronis apache2[1261]:  *
Mar 01 16:07:41 kotronis systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

So, what is the problem? Inside Apache logs I don't get any error either..

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this help, [from apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html):

> ````
> Overlapping Listen directives will result in a fatal error which
> will prevent the server from starting up.
>
> (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address
> [::]:80
>
> See the discussion in the wiki for further troubleshooting tips. ```
> ````